# COUNT but it counts nulls?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, count

Someone posted this solution for the exercise below and it confuses me as to how this could be the correct approach. The question specifies that where there is a post with no commments it should still appear with number_of_comments as '0'. How does the code below which uses simple COUNT manage to make the NULL a 0 when I know usually COUNT would ignore NULLS altogether?

**Solution:**

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT(s.sub_id) as post_id,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(t.sub_id)) 
FROM submissions t 
WHERE t.parent_id = s.sub_id) AS number_of_comments 

FROM submissions s 
WHERE s.parent_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY post_id
```

**This is the exercise that I was attempting:**

Table: Submissions

| Column Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| sub_id | int |
| parent_id | int |

There is no primary key for this table, it may have duplicate rows.
Each row can be a post or comment on the post.
parent_id is null for posts.
parent_id for comments is sub_id for another post in the table.

Write an SQL query to find number of comments per each post.

Result table should contain post_id and its corresponding number_of_comments, and must be sorted by post_id in ascending order.

Submissions may contain duplicate comments. You should count the number of unique comments per post.

Submissions may contain duplicate posts. You should treat them as one post.

The query result format is in the following example:

Submissions table:

| sub_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Null |
| 2 | Null |
| 1 | Null |
| 12 | Null |
| 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 6 | 7 |

Result table:

| post_id | number_of_comments |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 12 | 0 |

The post with id 1 has three comments in the table with id 3, 4 and 9. The comment with id 3 is repeated in the table, we counted it only once.
The post with id 2 has two comments in the table with id 5 and 10.
The post with id 12 has no comments in the table.
The comment with id 6 is a comment on a deleted post with id 7 so we ignored it.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT t.sub_id)`, to make code clearer.

Comment: What a weird table. It's called `submissions`, contains a submission ID (or that's what I suppose is what `sub_id` stands for), but the submission identifier doesn't identify a submission. What the heck?

Comment: I'd probably start the query with `with good_table as (select distinct sub_id, post_id from submissions)` to get a table without duplicates. Then you can remove both `DISTINCT` from your query and simply use `COUNT(*)` to count the rows belonging to a parent.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the code below which uses simple COUNT manage to make the NULL a 0 when I know usually COUNT would ignore NULLS altogether?

Your query looks correct, so this appears to be your question.

`COUNT()` never returns a `NULL` value.  If all values are `NULL`, then it returns `0`.  If there are no rows, then it returns `0`.  If there is a `GROUP BY` and no rows match, then no rows are returned (as opposed to `NULL` values).

For example, both of these return `0`:

```
select count(null)
from dual;

select count(null)
from dual
where 1 = 0;  -- no rows are selected
```

There is one case where there might be confusion.  The following returns `NULL`:

```
select (select cnt from (select count(*) as cnt from dual) c where 1 = 0)
from dual;
```

However, what is happening here is the following:

- The innermost subquery is returning 1 row with a value of 0.
- The outer subquery is returning no rows.  A subquery that returns no rows returns `NULL`.

By the way, these are the rules of SQL; these are not special rules for Oracle.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c7101f1383b18b15845c99602a779657) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Your points stand for when you're doing a count across the entire table, but you can get no rows returned for a count with a predicate and a `GROUP BY` present, e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dual WHERE 1=0 GROUP BY dummy;`

Comment: @Boneist . . . Even in that case, `COUNT()` does not return `NULL`.

Comment: Apologies, I should have included the quote from your answer I was responding to: "If there are no rows, then it returns 0". As I demonstrated, that's not true if there's a `GROUP BY` present.